# how to add custom header upload to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, flask-restful, custom-headers

I use Flask to create an API, but I am having trouble uploading when I create custom headers to upload to my Google Cloud Storage. Fyi, the permissions details on my server are the same as my local machine to test upload of images to GCS, admin storage and admin object storage, there are no problems on my local machine. but when I curl or test upload on my server to my Google Cloud Storage bucket, the response is always the same:

"rc": 500,
    "rm": "403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/konxxxxxx/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', )"

im testing in postman using custom header :
upload_key=asjaisjdaozmzlaljaxxxxx

and i curl like this :
url --location --request POST 'http://14.210.211.xxx:9001/koxxx/upload_img?img_type=img_x' --header 'upload_key: asjaisjdaozmzlaljaxxxxx' --form 'img_file=@/home/user/image.png'

and I have confirmed with "gcloud auth list" that the login data that I use on the server is correct and the same with my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a permission error, to fix it use service accounts method, it's easy and straightforward.

- create a service account

  gcloud iam service-accounts create \
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
      --display-name $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
- add permissions to your service account

  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_NAME \
      --role roles/bigtable.user \
      --member serviceAccount:$SA_EMAIL
  $SA_EMAIL is the service account here. you can get it using:

  SA_EMAIL=$(gcloud iam service-accounts list \
      --filter="displayName:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME" \
      --format='value(email)')
- download the service account to a destination $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEST and save it to variable $KEY

export KEY=$(gcloud iam service-accounts keys create $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEST --iam-account $SA_EMAIL)

- upload to Cloud Storage Bucket using the rest api:

  curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT_LOCATION] \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"

Comment: thanks before for you answer, but I have tried as above and the results are still the same, what I am trying to do again:
1. Change the SA to be the project owner
2. upload using bearer key, and I got the key from "gcloud auth print-access-token"
3. because I use a service account where is using json files. I have activated the SA name using the json file. use "gcloud auth activate-service-account SA name --key-file = / path / *. json --project = project-id
4. and gcloud init i choose SA name where is connect the json files.

and that doesn't solve the problem :((

Comment: there is something I don't understand in your comment; what do you mean by "upload using bearer key, and I got the key from "gcloud auth print-access-token" " . you should use the key file generated by the service account as a bearer key no the one from "gcloud auth print-access-token"

Comment: thanks, i got resolve my problem. i just export file json after i pull and recompile the code. and i set variable file json to static in my env file.
file json is credential service account from google.
thanks.